# find typename of typename in template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, std, type-traits, typename

I would like the following code to compile when foo gets anything derived from base, otherwise a compile error ensues. I have written the type-trait class is_Base because the `std::is_base_of` does not work well with my template stuff. I am close. I got it to work using a `static_passoff` thing, but I would like to not have to use it. So how can write the enable_if without the `static_passoff` hack? Here is the running version: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6de5171b6d3e12ff

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template < typename D >
class Base
{
public:
    typedef D EType;
};

template<class T>
struct is_Base
{
    using base_type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;

    template<class U>
    static constexpr std::true_type test(Base<U> *) { return std::true_type(); }
    static constexpr std::false_type test(...) { return std::false_type(); }

    using value = decltype( test((T*)0) );
};

template < typename A >
using static_passoff = std::integral_constant< bool, A::value >;

template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if< static_passoff< typename is_Base< T >::value >::value >::type >
void foo(T const&)
{
}


class Derived : public Base<Derived> {};
class NotDerived {};


int main()
{
    Derived d;
    //NotDerived nd;

    foo(d);
    //foo(nd); // <-- Should cause compile error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::is_base_of does not work well with my ... stuff`. See Scott Meyer's "Effective Modern C++" item 27. You need `std::is_base_of<Base, std::decay_t<T>>::value`.

Comment: @kfsone `Base` is a class template.

Comment: Well, you get my point. See http://ideone.com/d3Of8G

Comment: @kfsone You don't get my point. `Base` is a class template. Not a class.

Comment: @Barry it is in his code, I'm not referencing his code. `std::is_base_of<TheBaseYouWantToTestAgainst, std::decay_t<T>>::value`. Happy?

Comment: @kfsone He wants to test against *any* `Base<U>`. Not one specific `Base`.

Comment: @kfsone I want to be able to test if something is of the base type without caring about template types. My `is_Base` thing does that very cleanly.

Comment: `std::is_base_of<std::decay_t<U>, std::decay_t<T>>::value`.

Comment: @kfsone the code is a part of my question. I don't care about `is_base_of` or `decay_t` as they do not help me one bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question given that your code does work. But stylistically, for metafunctions that yield a type, that type should be named `type`. So you should have:

```
using type = decltype( test((T*)0) );
      ^^^^
```

Or, to avoid the zero-pointer-cast-hack:

```
using type = decltype(test(std::declval<T*>()));
```

Also, your `test` doesn't need a definition. Just the declaration. We're not actually *calling* it, just checking its return type. It doesn't have to be `constexpr` either, so this suffices:

```
template<class U>
static std::true_type test(Base<U> *);
static std::false_type test(...);
```

Once you have that, you can alias it:

```
template <typename T>
using is_Base_t = typename is_Base<T>::type;
```

And use the alias:

```
template <typename T, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t< is_Base_t<T>::value>>
void foo(T const&)
{
}
```

Comment: I defined the functions to get rid of the clang warnings. That alias is very similar to my passoff hack. Isn't there a way to just say `is_Base<T>::type::value` inside the enable_if?

Comment: @Cory Yeah. Type exactly that.

Comment: I get an error. I have tried adding `typename` in various places, but I guess I just don't know the propper format.

Comment: Oh, ok. No `typename` at all. Haha. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know they added the `_t` type alias' in c++14. The alias solution is certainly cleaner. I will now accept this answer.

Comment: Aparently the plural of alias is aliases.

Comment: @Cory Not alii? That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

After stumbling blindly into the answer in the comments, I found out I can just use `is_Base<T>::type::value` without any `typename` keywords. When trying to remove the `static_passoff` before, I kept putting in `typename`. I have always been mixed up with that one. Anyway, here is the final code with a few teaks from Barry's answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template < typename D >
class Base
{
public:
    typedef D EType;
};

template<class T>
struct is_Base
{
    using base_type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;

    template<class U>
    static constexpr std::true_type test(Base<U> *) { return std::true_type(); }
    static constexpr std::false_type test(...) { return std::false_type(); }

    using type = decltype(test(std::declval<T*>()));
};

template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if< is_Base< T >::type::value >::type >
void foo(T const&)
{
}


class Derived : public Base<Derived> {};
class NotDerived {};


int main()
{
    Derived d;
    //NotDerived nd;

    foo(d);
    //foo(nd); // <-- Should cause compile error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor, assuming Barry won't stone me for a comment, you could reduce the `using base_type` to `using base_type = std::decay_t<T>` or C++11 `using base_type = typename std::decay<T>::type;` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)

Comment: @kfsone I take it back. It looks like `decay` would be useful here.